# Git SSH "Permission denied" between two servers

Tags: git, ssh

I have two servers with Git installed (version 2.7), one is a "development" server, and the other is a "production" server. When I try to push my master repository on my development server to my production server with

```
 git push live master
```

I get an error saying:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is this saying that the SSH isn't working? I've chmod'd the .ssh file to 700 and the authorized_keys file to 600. I changed the repo to 766. Here's my git config on my development server:

```
[remote "live"]
        url = ssh://admin@PRODUCTION-IP-ADDRESS/home/admin/repo/site.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/live/*
```

I've been trying to look for a solution but everything I've come across is for Github. Does git know to look for ~/.ssh?

Comment: Have you deployed the keys to both servers? private & public appropriately?

Comment: you should try "ssh admin@PROdDUCTION_IP_ADDRESS" and you should be able to log in.... when logged in, check if "/home/admin/repo/site.git" exists.

Comment: and make sure that you have ":" after your ip-address; something like this: "ssh://admin@PRODUCTION-IP-ADDRESS:/home/admin/repo/site.git"

Comment: and yes, git knows to look for ~/.ssh :)

Comment: Any chance your key is *not* named id_rsa? Also, hoping OS is linux.

Comment: thanks for the help all, didn't have SSH keys on both sides, didn't know that was needed. Git's working now. I guess I will keep this up in case anyone else is googling the same problem one day and needs a reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely forgot to try to ssh admin@PRODUCTION_IP_ADDRESS with my terminal from my development server. Couldn't connect, didn't have keys on both sides, only had the Production SSH key on the development server and not the other way around. Didn't know that before.